# AS3 Resize bitmap object to fit in a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using the following code to get an image from a webcam. The problem that I am facing is that I need to fit "bitmap" to mcVideo. I can't just do mcVideo.addChild(bitmap), because the bitmap is larger than mcVideo. How do I fit bitmap into mcVideo for preview purposes?

Thanks!

```
var bandwidth:int = 0;
var quality:int = 100;

var cam:Camera;
var video:Video;
var captureVideo:Video;
var bitmapData:BitmapData;
var bitmap:Bitmap;    

public function Main() {

    mcCapture.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mcCapture_Click);

    cam = Camera.getCamera();
    cam.setQuality(bandwidth, quality);
    cam.setMode(640,480,30,false);

    // The display object:
    video = new Video();
    video.attachCamera(cam);
    video.width = mcVideo.width;
    video.height = mcVideo.height;

    mcVideo.addChild(video);

    // Bitmap to capture full 640x480
    bitmapData = new BitmapData(cam.width, cam.height);
    bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    bitmap.width = cam.width;
    bitmap.height = cam.height;

    trace("Set bitmap width: " + bitmap.width + " Height: " + bitmap.height);

}

public function mcCapture_Click(e:Event):void {

    bitmapData.draw(video);


            // Code to display preview

    trace("done");

}
```

Comment: it's created in flash as a movieclip on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `addChild()` and then set the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties of the MC to about 0.5 or 0.2 to scale the bitmap to fit on screen.

Or you could use a custom function to draw only a portion of the bitmap, cropping it.

```
var g:Graphics = MC.graphics;
g.beginBitmapFill(...)
g.drawRect(...)
g.endFill()
```